# CÓmo bloquear scroll hacia arriba

Tags: javascript, jquery

Llevo buscando toda la tarde en google para resolver el siguiente problema.

Imaginense un `header` un `nav` y `section` (por este orden) en el `header` tengo un `slider` que tiene un `width:100%` y un `height` variable dependiendo del dispositivo o de si el usuario hace más pequeño su navegador desde el pc, en todo caso el `height` será del 100% también.

Mi problema es el siguiente. Cuando un usuario pulsa en un botón del `nav` quiero que pueda hacer `scroll`, pero nunca mas arriba del `nav`, es decir, que no pueda ver el `header` (al pulsar el botón del `nav` automáticamente se desliza la pagina hacia abajo de forma que en pantalla se visualiza el `nav` y `section`).

Adjuntaria el código pero en este momento no tengo las claves de los servidores y no tengo manera de acceder a la web.

Un cordial saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento `scroll` no puede ser cancelado. Pero puede hacerlo cancelando estos eventos de interacción:
`Mouse` & `Touch scroll` y `Botones` asociados con el desplazamiento.

#### [[DEMO FUNCIONANDO](http://output.jsbin.com/xatidu/4/)]

> Para probar el funcionamiento del demo:
>
> Pulse el botón `enable scrolling` o `disable scrolling`

```
// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // FF más viejo
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // estándar moderno
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // navegadores más antiguos, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // móvil
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

> Aquí esta la [respuesta original SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/8933039) por [galambalazs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378024/galambalazs)

#### Otra alternativa es esta:

Hazlo simplemente agregando una clase al cuerpo:

```
.stop-scrolling {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Agregue la clase y luego elimine cuando desee volver a habilitar el desplazamiento, probado en IE, FF, Safari y Chrome.

```
$('body').addClass('stop-scrolling')
```

Para **dispositivos móviles**, necesitarás manejar el evento `touchmove`:

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()})
```

Y desvincular para volver a habilitar el desplazamiento. Probado en iOS6 y Android 2.3.3

```
$('body').unbind('touchmove')
```

Si necesita mas información al respecto (Traducir del Inglés):

> - [Deshabilitar el desplazamiento hacia arriba pasado el punto específico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18925451/8933039)
> - [¿Cómo evito el desplazamiento hacia abajo en javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9817268/8933039)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, utilice tu segunda respuesta fue lo mas sencillo.

Comment: @Jonatan comprendo, me alegra haber ayudado, es que cuando preguntas debes colocar toda la info necesaria en la pregunta por ejemplo el código que tenias realizado hasta el momento :)

Comment: Si, lo tendré en cuenta. Ayer mismo no pude aportar el codigo porque no tenia acceso al servidor (cambiaran la pass) y la verdad es que me urgia bastante este asunto. Pero como bien dije lo tendre en cuenta para proximas duda. Gracias de nuevo